# How to install my own python program as an app (on chromebook with Linux Beta)

Tags: python, linux

I have created a simple python program using tKinter's turtle module, and I would like to turn it into an app that I can open by clicking an app icon, but I do not know how to do so (I am kinda a noob whose only experience is taking a computer science class at school). I am also doing this on Linux beta on a chromebook. I have looked at some other stack overflow posts, but they only go into making it easily runable from the terminal. I wanted a full-fledged app icon as if it is a normal app, which might be asking for too much since I'm still a noob, but hey, I won't know til I try.

Comment: does Chromebook linux have sudo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Chromebook linux does indeed have sudo